# Unit testing angular $log with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am running into some challenges unit testing $log.

I wanted to try a simple test that took the value I injected and tested.  I am not hooking the spec up to a restful call yet. I am using angular mocks.  Here are my before each statements.  I have the module defined through angular mocks.  Some of what I have been testing has came from this blog
 http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/08/ngmock-fundamentals-log/.

In my devDependencies

```
"angular": "^1.5.0",
"angular-mocks": "^1.5.0",
```

I am using gulp to set up the tests.

```
gulp.task('test:jasmine',  function (done) { // move to return async when execution metrics done

gulp.src('./Scripts/tests/modules/utility/services/ha-http.service.jasmine.test.js')
    .pipe(jasmine({
        verbose: true
    }))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('jasmine end');
        done();
    });
```

});

So I know the versions of angular and mocks are matched up.

```
beforeEach(function () {

    angular.mock.module('ha.module.utility');

    angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend, haHttpService) {
        http = $httpBackend;
        service = haHttpService;
    });
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_$log_) {
    $log = _$log_;
}));

afterEach(function () {

    http.flush();
    http.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    http.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

The test itself is just making sure I have $log working.

```
it('should call logs', function () {
    $log.info('it worked');
    expect($log.info.logs).toContain(['it worked']);
});
```

However I am returning

```
ReferenceError: inject is not defined
```

************* Update ***********

I did set up $log in the mock module

```
angular.mock.module('ha.module.utility', function ($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('$log', function ($delegate) {
                return $delegate;
            });

        });



angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend, haHttpService, $log) {
            http = $httpBackend;
            service = haHttpService;
            console.log($log);
        });
```

I am getting the output I want in the console.log($log) when I run my gulp test.  However,  $log still returns

```
ReferenceError: $log is not defined
```

in the spec.

Comment: Is this the file in its entirety?  Do you define any `describe` functions?

Comment: Yeah, I am describing the service     describe('haHttpService', function () {

Comment: I have a few other tests that I omitted to save space

Answer (score 0):

> ReferenceError: inject is not defined

means that `inject` global was not defined, literally. It is [defined](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2769) in angular-mocks.js [on condition](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2563).

The problem is caused by testing rig and not the specs. angular-mocks.js may not be loaded, or it may be loaded *before* Jasmine.

Comment: This was my concern initially, but I have this all loaded through node with no script tags on the client side.  Everything is done via the npm.

Comment: NPM fetches "angular" and "angular-mocks" packages to node_modules and that's all it does, it has nothing to do with their loading. You haven't provided details on how do you run tests but you should investigate your testing rig (Karma-powered or anything else) if it loads  "angular" and "angular-mocks" properly.

Comment: This is just the basics of me learning how to test.  I am running everything through gulp.  I set up a config file with jsdom.